# Standing and sitting while using a computer at work

Tags: ergonomics

I would like to be able to comfortably switch between sitting and standing while at work (I'm a software developer, so I spend most of my day in front of a computer). For the past couple of months I have been using a large elevated stand that sits on my desk (designed expressly for this purpose) containing my keyboard and mouse, and my monitors have been raised as high as possible and aimed upwards. So I can stand all day and I'm pretty comfortable (my right wrist may be at too much of an angle when it's on my mouse, but that's a separate issue).

The only problem is that sometimes I want to be able to sit. I can easily place my keyboard and mouse back down *under* the elevated stand, but I have to look up pretty steeply and that is uncomfortable and makes it difficult to see the screens since they are tilted upwards. My monitor mounts are difficult to adjust quickly/easily, so I can't just re-aim them.

I would of course love one of those hydraulic standing/sitting desks (cost isn't the problem). But I'm in a row of "trader-style" desks where it's basically a very long surface with people sitting at 6-foot intervals.

What type of equipment do you recommend?

I suppose the best thing would be some sort of monitor stand (it must be able to hold 2-3 LCDs) that can easily be lowered and raised. But any other suggestions are also welcome.

Comment: I've seen elevator arms for a single display, but not for 2-3.  You could maybe use a large screen TV lift like this: http://www.rockler.com/product.cfm?page=30590&site=ROCKLER , and they have a smaller version of the same thing.

Comment: (There is probably a site somewhere dedicated to standing workstations, where they'd have other ideas.)

Comment: Why is this *on hold*? It's about *computer hardware* (both "how to ergonomically place my computer I/O devices" and "does hardware exist to allow standing/sitting operation" - though this latter hardware probably doesn't contain a CPU, it still qualifies as computer hardware) and I'm not looking for a specific product recommendation, just a way to handle standing and sitting, given that I can't replace my desk.

Comment: Why not just buy a tall chair that has a back and arms? e.g. http://www.brandnewchair.co.uk/product/RL-525ANR

Comment: A chair is by no definition "computer hardware". This is a physiology/ergonomics problem with a vague relation to computers and is not an actual problem with any kind of computer.  Your problem is in meatware and not hardware or software computer related at all. This site is not here to solve meat problems.  You need a physiologist or doctor or even a feng shui expert, not computer technical support. A pen can be used to store computer data on paper but we don't consider it computer hardware, the same goes for chairs and stands. Yes they're all hardware, they're just not *computer* hardware.

Comment: @Mokuabi Who said anything about chairs or doctors? I want to be able to switch between sitting and standing while using my computer (which is common these days, and usually done with specialized hardware designed expressly for that purpose). Specifically, I'm looking for hardware to hold pieces of my computer (monitor, keyboard, mouse) and such hardware has *only one* purpose in the entire world, holding computer hardware. This question revolves around computers and only computers.

Comment: @AdamBatkin Sorry but in that case you are off by two points.  Firstly hardware to support computer parts are not computer hardware as far as the [FAQ] is concerned (computer hardware refers specifically to the parts that make a computer do computing work, not shelves and stands that make humans work with computers), secondly product recommendations are off-topic on pretty much all StackExchange sites.

Comment: As an aside though, for discussions around computers you might be better off visiting the [chat] rooms where you might be able to find a few people who could discus these sorts of things with you.

Answer (score 0):

Ergotron makes some nice, sturdy products:

For your monitor/keyboard sit/stand option:

[Wall Mounted Swivel Mount](http://www.ergotron.com/ProductsDetails/tabid/65/PRDID/646/language/en-US/Default.aspx)

or

[Desk Mounted Swivel Mount](http://www.ergotron.com/Products/DeskMounts/tabid/71/Default.aspx)

Start there.